# python selenium check if cookie exist - isset - login successfull

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver

I want to check if my python selenium application is login successful, for this i need to check if cookies 'login_token' is set,  my code test is this bat not work :(

```
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
if cookies['login_token']:
    print 'login ok'
else:
    print 'login incorrect'
```

this code return else and the login is correct, where i'm wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_cookies()` method returns a **list of dictionaries**, and not a single dictionary.

Hence, to check if a cookie 'login_token' exists or not, we can do something like below:

```
cookies = driver.get_cookies() # returns list of dicts

login_status = False

for cookie in cookies:
    if cookie['name'] == 'login_token':
        login_status = True
        break

if login_status:
    print 'login ok'
else:
    print 'login incorrect'
```

Hope this helps.