# python selenium check if already logged in

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, automation

Im trying to automate some stuff and the program needs to login sometimes. I want to to check if already logged in and log in if not already logged in
the website is my router admin panel 192.168.0.254

Comment: can you add the website? you can check if a login cookie exists or just try to find the login button with xpath or css class.

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously we can't see your router admin panel because is in your LAN network.

But you can try to find the "log in " button with the xpath, css class, or another attribute.

For example, the xpath of the stackoverflow login button is:

```
/html/body/header/div/ol[2]/li[2]/a[1]
```

You can find it by selecting the development tools of your browser (F12 with Firefox), selecting the button and right click in the code from the inspector, and then "copy -> copy xpath".

If the element has a specific id, or class, it would be better, but I can't see your router admin panel.

And then, use the driver to find it with a try/except block:

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/div/ol[2]/li[2]/a[1]")
except:
    print('User is logged')
```

Or maybe, if you need it for another webpages, that could change their design, would be find if there is a login cookie, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749529/python-selenium-check-if-cookie-exist-isset-login-successfull).